# Querying data by joining two tables in two database on same servers

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables in two different databases in same server. database table are as below.

[image]

I want to get records of table 2 where `delivery_date` (date only. It means 2023-01-25) is equal to `logtime` date in table 1. **Delivery_date and logtime datetype is datetime**. Result should be as below.

[image]

I tried as below

```
SELECT * 
FROM Database2.table2  t2 
INNER JOIN Database1.table1  t1 
WHERE t2.delivery_date= t1.logtime AND t2.v_id='A001';
```

This is not getting what I want. how can I solve this.

Comment: Which dbms do you use?

Comment: BTW: Add sample data and expected result as text not as image

Comment: I am using MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert both date time values to date using the `DATE`-function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Database2.table2  t2 
INNER JOIN Database1.table1  t1 
on DATE(t2.delivery_date)= Date(t1.logtime) AND t2.v_id='A001';
```

If you do not do it, the complete date time value will be compared